# pygame.draw.line invalid syntax?

Tags: python, pygame

So, I'm following a tutorial which currently has me building the following for a quick look at drawing using pygame functions.

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init() #has to be called before any other pygame functions

#setup the window
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((500,400), 0, 32)
pygame.display.set_caption('Drawing')

#colors
black = (0, 0, 0, 0)
white = (255, 255, 255, 255)
red = (255, 0, 0)
green = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)

#draw on the surface object
DISPLAYSURF.fill(white)
pygame.draw.polygon(DISPLAYSURF, green, ((146,0), (291,106), (236,277), 
(56,277), (0,106))
pygame.draw.line(DISPLAYSURF, BLUE, (60, 60), (120, 60), 4)
pygame.draw.line(DISPLAYSURF, BLUE,(120,60), (60,120))
pygame.draw.line(DISPLAYSURF, BLUE,(60,120), (120,120), 4)
pygame.draw.circle(DISPLAYSURF, BLUE, (300,500), 20, 0)
pygame.draw.ellipse(DISPLAYSURF, red, (300, 250, 40, 80), 1)
pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAYSURF, red, (200,150,100,50))

pixObj = pygame.pixelarray(DISPLAYSURF)
pixObj[480][380] = black
pixObj[482][382] = black
pixObj[484][384] = black
pixObj[486][386] = black
pixObj[488][388] = black
del pixObj

#run game loop
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    pygame.display.update()
```

My problem is that in attempting to run this code, I get an invalid syntax error pointing to the first pygame.draw.line. If this is somehow a typo, I'll be kinda surprised, I retyped those lines several times to make sure they were correct, even double checked the docs to make sure that was still the valid syntax. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Focusing on that line:

`pygame.draw.polygon(DISPLAYSURF, green, ((146,0), (291,106), (236,277), 
(56,277), (0,106))`

Let's make some changes to it, that take valid syntax to valid syntax.

`pygame.draw.polygon(DISPLAYSURF, green, ((), (), (), (), ())`

`pygame.draw.polygon(DISPLAYSURF, green, ()`

`pygame.draw.polygon(`

There are more open parentheses than closing.

If the following lines are correct, you should remove an open paren after "green".

Comment: Actually, I think it's an extra close paren at the end - the numbers are the pointlist making up the shape.

Comment: Oh my goodness I was looking at the wrong line completely. I don't think I'll ever look at errors the same way again. Thanks so much for your help! I was actually missing a closing paren, but your comments lead me to it!